# Calling/Referring to a named Range from another Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I managed to write a code from different threads and code examples from around the web. It is trial and error and lots of copy-pasting.

I have several ranges defined within my subs:

```
Define range names:
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Name = "Type1"
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Name = "SubTotal1"
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:F8").Name = "Data1"

X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B11").Name = "Type2"
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16").Name = "SubTotal2"
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A13:F15").Name = "Data2"

X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B18").Name = "Type3"
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B23").Name = "SubTotal3"
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A20:F22").Name = "Data3"

Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:A6").Name = "Period"
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B6").Name = "Name"
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D6").Name = "Code"
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4:E6").Name = "Type"
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F4:K4").Name = "Data"
```

This name range is used in every sub (I have around 15, with around 165 more needed) for copying and inserting information from Workbook X to Workbook Y.

Since it is redundant to reuse the code, I would like to put these Ranges in a separate Sub and call on it in each new Sub.

I would also like to do the same with the following code, which refers to the ranges defined above:

```
'Insert Type1 Data from X:

If X.Sheets("Sheet").Range("SubTotal1").Value > 0 Then
Range("Type1").Copy
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Type").Insert xlShiftDown
Range("Data1").Copy
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Data").Insert xlShiftDown

'Insert Period:
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Copy
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Period").Insert xlShiftDown

'Insert Name:
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Copy
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Name").Insert xlShiftDown

'Insert Code Type:
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Copy
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Code").Insert xlShiftDown
End If
```

This code, and 6 more like it (Type 1-6) are also redundant in other Subs, so ideally, I would put it in a separate sub and call on it when necessary too. I use this at the beginning of my subs to define X and Y sheets:

```
Dim X As Workbook
Dim Y As Workbook

'Define workbooks:
Set X = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Folder\File.xlsx")
Set Y = ThisWorkbook
```

EDIT: To give a better example of what I mean, I imagine Subs going something like this:

```
Sub Sub1

Call Sub "RangeNames"
Call Sub "Insert Type1 Data while referring to RangeNames"
Call Sub "Insert Type2 Data while referring to RangeNames"

End Sub
```

And/Or

```
Sub Sub2

Call Sub "RangeNames"
Call Sub "If RangeName 'SubTotal 3' > 0 then Insert Type3 Data while referring to RangeNames"

End Sub
```

EDIT 2:

For @SJR:

```
Sub Sub1
Dim X As Workbook
Dim Y As Workbook

Set X = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Folder\File.xlsx")
Set Y = ThisWorkbook

X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Name = "Type1"
X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Name = "SubTotal1"

Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4:E6").Name = "Type"

Sub2

End Sub
```

Sub 2 is:

```
Sub Sub2

If X.Sheets("Sheet").Range("SubTotal1").Value > 0 Then <- ERROR HAPPENS HERE
Range("Type1").Copy
Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Type").Insert xlShiftDown

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Basically, what you are trying to do is copying and inserting the **same** kinds of data from one workbook to another. Is that right?

Comment: Hi @libzz! Yes, that is correct. To be exact, there will be several workbooks - around 10, but they will all contain the same kind of sheets/data, with all data in fixed locations, so the rows/sheet names will not change, only the values. It is basically monthly reports coming in, with all that information needed to be copied from them and inserted into rows in a master file in different sheets based on the report information. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What precisely is your question? Are you asking how to pass arguments?

Comment: @SJR, I am not sure what the correct terminology is, I am afraid, sorry. I basically want to find a way to introduce Named Ranges that I mentioned, as Subs, into other Subs that will then copy and paste information using the values in that Named Range Sub - to save space and make the code more efficient.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but once you have defined named ranges in one sub, you will able to reference them in other subs automatically (as you can access them via the sheet directly). You might want to read this http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: @SJR That was my initial attempt - but it seems like when Excel is using two Worksheets, those ranges are not referenced. I defined the Workbooks using X and Y, listed the Ranges, and then put the subs under it, but once it reaches the command including the Range, it gives me a "Object Required" error. My guess is that Ranges require specific directions when more than two Workbooks are used.

'

Comment: Could you post the code that errors please?

Comment: @SJR Sure, I edited the post to include the code, can't post it properly in the comments.

Comment: `Sub 2` doesn't know what `X` is so you would have declare it outside the first procedure. Some more reading matter! http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx However, in `Sub 2` you could just use `If Range("SubTotal1").Value > 0`

Comment: @SJR, I will take a look, thanks! Regarding the X, I tried putting the same `Dim X as Workbook` and gave it a `Set X =` path in Sub 2, but in that case the error happens in the same place saying – Application-defined or object-defined error. Any ideas?

Comment: `Dim X as Workbook` goes at the top of the module before the `Sub1` line. Then you define X in Sub1. Don't define it in Sub2 (I don't think there is any need anyway as previously stated) as it will "remember" the definition from Sub1.

Comment: @SJR Didn't know that I can move Dim X up, that's convenient. Cheers! Going through the code step by step, I just realized that it does seem to work in another sub. Maybe I need to debug this one more thoroughly. Will go through it and keep you updated. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest reading that second link. You might want to post another question to specifically ask about this and provide an [mcve].

Comment: @SJR Agreed, I should have limited the question to a more specific example. I was afraid I might not make sense if I post too little so decided to explain as much as I can. Will do better next time!

Comment: That's fine. The issue has just evolved into two separate issues, one concerned with scope of variables and the other to do with passing arguments to functions (as per @libzz's answer).

Comment: @SJR, it worked! I fixed some mistakes in definitions and it works like a charm. The code got reduced immensely too, each sub is now around 5 codes long, with a big sub in the beginning defining all the ranges and paths and such. It's beautiful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Libzz, turns out I won't be needing arguments, since this solution worked as well. But thank you for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 1):

What you need are arguments (aka parameters).

e.g.

```
Sub CopyAndInsertStuff(sourceLocation as String, destinationLocation as String)

    Set wbSrc = Workbooks(sourceLocation)
    Set wbDst = Workbooks(destinationLocation)

    'Do your copying and inserting logic here...

End Sub
```

Then call that function by:

```
Call CopyAndInsertStuff("C:\path\to\source\File.xlsx", "C:\path\to\destination\File.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try that and see if it works. Might require some tinkering first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at adding another 165 subs, may I suggest to have a look at **loops** and/or **arrays**?

It might take you over all about the same time to develop it (considering the learning curve), but the code will be about 150 times shorter (do everything in 1-2-3 subs), and much easier to maintain. This, and in conjunction with the suggested parameters to call similar functionality from other subs or functions, would be a lot more efficient.

Here are the first results from Google when it comes to loops and arrays, and after a quick look, they do cover the basic needs:

- **Loops**: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html
- **Arrays**: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html

Final advice, keep in mind that the less you interact with the workbooks from VBA, the faster your macros will run. ie: load your full range in an array, perform the transforming you want, then put it back in the workbook - you are only accessing the workbook 2 times as needed. If on the other hand, you use vba to copy cell A to cell B, few tens/hundreds of thousands times... it will be slower.

Comment: Hi DarXyde! Thanks for the links! I have seen mentions of loops and arrays before, but I could not find a way so far to modify my code to include them. Once my code is complete and I am certain of what tasks are being performed, I will most definitely look into optimization and replacing long codes with something more sophisticated. Right now, that stuff just makes my brain go nuts, unfortunately..